# Typescript with react-stripe-elements does not pass injected props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

Here is code relevant for Stripe.

From what I understand from the error `TypeScript` thinks `CheckoutForm` requires`stripe` prop, but it is not provided through `InjectedCheckoutForm` component.

On other hand `injectStripe` should inject props `stripe` and `elements` to wrapped component that is child of `elements`. https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#setting-up-your-payment-form-injectstripe

```js
type CreditCardProps = {
  secret: string
}

function StripeSection(props: CreditCardProps) {
  const { secret } = props

  return (
    <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_...">
      <Elements>
        <InjectedCheckoutForm secret={secret} />
      </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>
  )
}

type CheckoutFormProps = {
  stripe: ReactStripeElements.StripeProps
  secret: string
}

function CheckoutForm(props: CheckoutFormProps) {
  const { stripe, secret } = props
  const handleSubmit = async (
    event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
  ): Promise<void> => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const result = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(secret, {})
  }

  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardSection />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

const InjectedCheckoutForm = injectStripe(CheckoutForm)

function CardSection() {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Card details</label>
      <CardElement
        style={{ base: { fontSize: '18px', backgroundColor: 'white' } }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Property 'stripe' is missing in type '{ secret: string; }' but required in type 'CheckoutFormProps'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the resulting type definition for the `InjectedCheckoutForm` component would be:

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm: React.ComponentType<CheckoutFormProps>
```

The issue arises because the `InjectedCheckoutForm` itself doesn't expect a `stripe` prop - since its the one that's injecting that prop into its child (i.e., the `CheckoutFormComponent`)

The fix would be to define the expected types for the `InjectedCheckoutForm` component and pass them in as a type argument like so:

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = injectStripe<{ secret: string }>(CheckoutForm);
```

Which would result in a type definition for InjectedCheckoutForm like:

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm: React.ComponentType<{
  secret: string;
}>
```

That component takes in a secret as you've written, it injects stripe into it the `CheckoutForm` component and forwards along the secret!