# I am trying to integrate stripe frontend in my react and redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am using react and redux in my project i already integrated complete backend in spring boot
and by following this tutorial i am trying to integrate frontend in react https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-consumer [image]

This is my frontend

```
export class RecurringSubscription extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_123');

    const CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS = {
      style: {
        base: {
          color: '#32325d',
          fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
          fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
          fontSize: '16px',
          '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4',
          },
        },
        invalid: {
          color: '#fa755a',
          iconColor: '#fa755a',
        },
      },
    };

    return (
      <div className="client-recurring-subscription">
        <main>
          <section className="section" style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <div className="card card-info">
                    <div className="card-header">
                      <h3 className="card-title"> Payment</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-12 my-auto mx-auto">
                          <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                            <MyCheckoutForm stripe={stripePromise} projectId={projectId} userId={userId} />
                          </Elements>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    client: state.client,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...actions }, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RecurringSubscription);
```

This is MyCheckoutForm Component

```
 class CheckoutForm {
  handleSubmit = async () => {
    const { stripe, elements,projectId,userId } = this.props;
    console.log(stripe);
    console.log(elements);
    console.log(projectId); //udefined
    console.log(userId); // unndefied

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not loaded yet. Make sure to disable
      // form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    // Get a reference to a mounted CardElement. Elements knows how
    // to find your CardElement because there can only ever be one of
    // each type of element.
    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: cardElement,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log('[error]', error);
    } else {
      console.log('[PaymentMethod]', paymentMethod);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { stripe } = this.props;
    console.log(stripe);
    return (
      <div>
        <CardElement />
        <br />
        <button
          className="btn-sm btn"
          type="submit"
          disabled={!stripe}
          onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}
        >
          Pay
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function InjectedCheckoutForm = () => {
  return (
    <ElementsConsumer>
      {({ elements, stripe }) => <CheckoutForm elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />}
    </ElementsConsumer>
  );
};
```

Now my issue
1- What is the role of InjectedCheckoutForm?
2- And How should i complete this integration ?

Whenever i click pay button element prop is undefined!!

Comment: There is some explanation here: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements. it looks like a component you should import and use as is, not implement a version of your own...

Comment: This may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892819/typescript-with-react-stripe-elements-does-not-pass-injected-props

Comment: Should `CheckoutForm` extend `React.Component`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injected form is a way to separate the concern of bringing in the `<ElementsConsumer>` to provide `stripe` and `elements` to render your component.

In your case, you're exporting your `CheckoutForm` (rather than the `InjectedCheckoutForm` ) so your `RecurringSubscription` component is loading `CheckoutForm` without elements quite explicitly. It would be expected then that `elements` prop is undefined.

You should change your `CheckoutForm` file to instead `export default InjectedCheckoutForm;` at the end and see if that resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Nolan, I made changes as you suggest and it works fine now i am facing an issue in Recurring Subscription component i am passing two extra prop suppose productId and userId with stripe={stripePromise} productId={productId} and userId={userId} ,so in CheckoutForm both the new props are undefined i edited the code Please see and suggest me